# Scenes are not loading

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

Something really odd happens when I'm trying to load a scene.

[image: image1]

The code that generates an error (I guess):

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

    public class playSc : MonoBehaviour {
    public string levelToLoad;

    public Animator menumusic;
    public GameObject background;
    public GameObject text;
    public GameObject progressSlider;
    public Text progressText;
    public Slider progressBar;

    private int loadProgress = 0;


    public void close()
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }
    public void play()
    {
        menumusic.SetBool("FadeOUT", true);
        GameObject.Find("Clock").SetActive(false);
        progressText.text = "Think about the Universe to continue.\nThinking progress:";
        StartCoroutine(DisplayLoadingScreen("Game"));
    }
    public void credits()
    {
        menumusic.SetBool("FadeOUT", true);
        GameObject.Find("Clock").SetActive(false);
        progressText.text = "Think about your behaviour.\nThinking progress:";
        StartCoroutine(DisplayLoadingScreen("Credits"));
    }
    IEnumerator DisplayLoadingScreen(string level)
    {

        background.SetActive(true);
        text.SetActive(true);
        progressSlider.SetActive(true);

        AsyncOperation async = SceneManager.LoadSceneAsync(level);
        while (!async.isDone)
        {
            loadProgress = (int)(async.progress * 100);
            progressBar.value = loadProgress;
            yield return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to use Application.LoadLevel() and it still is not working. It was working with this code but at one moment it stopped.

Comment: Hi, you always ask uncompleted questions. What platform does this problem happen on? Does it work on the Editor? What is your Unity version?

Comment: @Programmer sorry. Android. Yes, everything works in Editor. Unity 5.5.0p3

Comment: Oh my God. After 6 hours I've found where was an error. I marked Split Application Binary.

Comment: Interesting. Why should Split Binary cause the load function to stop working?

Comment: @Programmer idk. I marked it to see what will happen and then forgot about it.

Comment: Well I think you can now see what happens when you enable it...I suggest you file for a bug report because that shouldn't happen. Happy coding!